# Comments from less file to css production file

Tags: html, css, webpack, comments, webpack-5

How to keep comments that are in my less file to go to the CSS production file (webpack 5)?

note: If I leave some comment in CSS file, it shows in CSS production file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/* purgecss start ignore */` with `/*! purgecss start ignore */` and it should work